# Scala List with only subclasses

Tags: list, scala, seq, subclass

Is there a way to have a List["only subclasses of DataElement"] or List["only with trait Element"]?

I thought it could be like this

`val test: List[_ <: DataElement] = List(DataElement("hi"), DataMessage("ho"))`

with `DataMessage extends DataElement`

But i get this error

`type mismatch; found : DataMessage.type required: DataElement`

Answer (score 1):

Works for me:

```
trait Element
class DataElement(s: String) extends Element
class DataMessage(s: String) extends DataElement(s)

val test: List[_ <: DataElement] = List(new DataElement("hi"), new DataMessage("ho"))
println(test) // List(Test$DataElement$1@13c695a6, Test$DataMessage$1@17386918)
```

But you don't need the `_ <:` syntax.  These are better:

```
val test: List[DataElement] = List(new DataElement("hi"), new DataMessage("ho"))
val test: List[Element] = List(new DataElement("hi"), new DataMessage("ho"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, my problem was due to the companion objects for the classes.

Comment: maybe you should edit your question so that it has the context?  it's kind of hard to just guess what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

You are overcomplicating things a bit.  You can just do this:

```
val test: List[DataElement] = List(DataElement("hi"), DataMessage("ho"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, my problem was due to the companion objects for the classes.